# Python: How to avoid type error in with datetime? TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python

I am trying to apply the below function to a dataset with two columns containing a start and an end date (`start` and `end`).

```
import datetime as dt
end_date = dt.date(2010,1,1)
start_date = dt.date(2009, 4, 1)
num_months = (end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month)
```

The entries in both columns have the format `2017-07-01`. If I replace the date entries above by the column names e.g. `end_date = dt.date(df.end)`, I run into the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How can I avoid this kind of error?

Comment: Can you please clearify what df stands for? Also I'm guessing dt stands for datetime?

Comment: That is my dataframe that contains the column "end".

Comment: How did you create this dataframe? pandas? numpy? there is no way we can help you without more inforamtion about df... It would be helpful to see the code that created df.

Comment: Why do you think what amounts to a list of values would work as an argument to `dt.date`?

Comment: I read an excel file with pandas to create the dataframe and it contained this column. I used the 'df = pd.read_excel' command.

Comment: so the date column will contain a string as date format ?you want to convert it to datetime

Comment: I think so? How can I determine the data format of the column?